# What can a class do that a function cannot? (Python)

Tags: python

In the realm of Python:

What can a class do that a function cannot, other than organizing code/design pattern?

Couldn't one technically write any class via functions? Not to say that it would be more efficient or readable but in terms of pure functionality.

Said differently, can someone take **any** class and rewrite it using only functions?

Comment: Sounds like you need to take a better look to purpose of the classes. Yes you can use them as a organization, but a class is the building block of the OOP programming. And for an example you can have a class carry some sort of data (let's say a point in 3D) and methods to manipulate the data.

Comment: @MSH couldn't a function do that too?

Comment: I mean, technically you *can* program anything with just a Turing machine.

Comment: One more thing, using classes you can create objects which can store data and also mutate them.

Comment: No, a function can't (generally speaking) encapsulate data. Programming with only functions involves passing data around from function to function. Classes let you package that up conveniently in one object.

Comment: @CrazyChucky the question is, can it be done? Not what the "better" method is. Isnt technically a class made from a function?

Comment: @PranavaMohan a function cannot create an object and mutate it?

Comment: @mikelowry No, a function cannot be used to create an object.

Comment: @PranavaMohan: That can be done with functions alone using closures. An outer function defines variables and some inner functions. The inner functions all get attached as attributes to one inner function, which gets returned. The inner functions use `nonlocal` declarations for closure state they need to modify, and all of them from a given call share a unique closure state. It's ugly, but has a couple advantages: Greater encapsulation (digging into closure scope is harder than grubbing through instance attributes) and better performance (closure lookups are cheaper than `self.name` lookups)

Comment: @PranavaMohan i dont think that's correct, when you're creating an instance of a class you do so by invoking the classes constructor which is (special member) function, but a function nonetheless.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes you are right.

Comment: [Here's a truly stupid example of this sort of abuse](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSEgPzOvRKNCR6FS04pLAQhAgkWpBTmJyanxFRoVUFEQKEotKS3KQ9aBoaFSo5I4DQUl8QVFIGEk5RCBNCWN6opaHYXqylpNJYgGuHP04CwFW4QoDjWVSGoq0dSArQLKw5zBheRchLlcBSA1EOcb6igYaQIF9KDOBjKNwAYg7NMwNAALw5T8/w8A "Python 3 – Try It Online"); it can't do operator overloading or runtime polymorphism like class instances, but it's surprisingly functional.

Comment: You can add a functionality to an object created from a class. Let's say you have a function `s()` you can attache it to an object created from a class. Same goes with data. You can change (depends but mostly) the data and even have callback functions for when data changed.

Comment: @MSH understood, i believe a function can do that as well. I would refer to dark rangers answers as he explained it well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

About the only largely unique, commonly used, features I can think of off-hand is that classes can be polymorphic, and classes can use operator overloading.

Nested functions using closure scope can do most of the stateful attribute things a class does by having each closure act as an "instance" with the function(s) defined in that closure scope sort of acting like methods, so in that sense, you could write really ugly code with "methods" sharing persistent state.

But runtime dynamic polymorphism isn't an option (you could choose different functions to return closing over that shared state, but it won't let you have polymorphic extensions in any sane way).

You also can't simulate existing types that overload operators; operator overloading must be done on the type, not the instance, and all user-defined functions share a single type which doesn't let you overload additional operators.

To be clear, there are things you can do with classes that are *better* done with functions. In particular, writing your own iterable and paired iterator classes is a pain, but generator functions can be used to make iterators with no classes at all, or to define the `__iter__` of an iterable without needing to write the incredible ugliness that is a user-defined iterator class. Basically, they both exist, use the one that's clearly tailored for the situation at hand.

Comment: This is a solid answer, thank you for elucidating! Cant you have function overloading in the global scope though?

Comment: @mikelowry: In the sense of always writing `add(x, y)` instead of `x + y`? Sure. But a lot of this stuff is implicit in Python (e.g. use of `__repr__` and `__str__` overloads, use of `__bool__` for implicit truthiness testing, etc.), and you'd need to write and explicitly call functions or quasi-methods that perform said conversions, Python would never do it for you. No `if quasi_instance:` (a function is always truthy), you're stuck with `if is_true(quasi_instance):` or `if quasi_instance.is_true():`. No `print(quasi_instance)`, it's `print(quasi_instance.as_str())`, etc. A royal pain.